# Define a varbinary(max) column using sqlalchemy on MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm querying an SQL Server database using SQLAlchemy and need to cast a column to varbinary(max). The thing I am struggling with is the "max" part. I can get the cast to work for any actual number (say varbinary(20)), but I cannot find how to get it to work for the "max" size of the varbinary column.

Any pointers? Links? Solutions?

Regards,
Mark

Comment: I don't have any experience working with SQLAlchemy, but [according to this page](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/sqlalchemy/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Binary) the `length` parameter is optional and defaults to `None`. Could it be that `None` represents "MAX"?

Comment: unfortunately not. That just produces a CAST(x as VARBINARY) that then causes a "The column would be truncated" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you've all noticed we have virtually this exact recipe in the main documentation for custom compilation, without any monkeypatching, here:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/ext/compiler.html?highlight=compiler#changing-compilation-of-types

```
@compiles(String, 'mssql')
@compiles(VARCHAR, 'mssql')
def compile_varchar(element, compiler, **kw):
    if element.length == 'max':
        return "VARCHAR('max')"
    else:
        return compiler.visit_VARCHAR(element, **kw)

foo = Table('foo', metadata,
    Column('data', VARCHAR('max'))
)
```

Comment: @Mike: Strange, but haven't seen this one before. Would this be the best way to handle db-migration where the type(s) are missing in the target DB: say, migrating `BIT` from `mssql` to `sqlite`?

Comment: A very nice solution. I'll have to look into the compiler extension a bit more.

Comment: I don't think we have BIT as a base type, it would be easiest just to subclass UserDefinedType: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/sqlalchemy/types.html?highlight=userdefinedtype#sqlalchemy.types.UserDefinedType

Answer (score 2):

SQLAlchemy does not support this out of the box (create a feature request on [sqlalchemy trac](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/query)).

In order to make it work for you, hack it: add the following method to the `MSTypeCompiler` class in `sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py`:

```
def visit_VARBINARY(self, type_):
    if type_.length == 'MAX':
        return "VARBINARY(MAX)"
    else:
        return "VARBINARY(%d)" % type_.length
```

and then use the query with the `MSVarBinary` type:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base import MSVarBinary
...
q = ... cast(mytable.c.mycolumn, MSVarBinary('MAX')) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The sqlalchemy team resolved this issue based on this thread (Power of community!). You can find it here [Large Text/Binary Type Deprecation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/mssql.html?highlight=varbinary%20max)

To use *VARBINARY(max)* use *LargetBinary* as datatype, and set the flag *deprecate_large_types=True*

From the site; create an engine with the flag *deprecate_large_types=True*:

```
eng = create_engine("mssql+pymssql://user:pass@host/db",deprecate_large_types=True)
```

When this flag is *True*, the UnicodeText, Text and LargeBinary datatypes, when used to render DDL, will render the types NVARCHAR(max), VARCHAR(max), and VARBINARY(max), respectively. This is a new behavior as of the addition of this flag.